# How to Mock GetUserId and IsAuthenticated from IIdentity without ControllerContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, ninject

Is there a easy way to Mock IIdentity.GetUserId and IIdentity.IsAuthenticated?

I've tested this way and got a **NotSupportedException**.

```
[Test]
public void CanGetUserIdFromIdentityTest()
{
    //Enviroment
    var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
    mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("test@test.com");
    mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.GetUserId()).Returns("12345");

    var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

    //Action
    Kernel.Rebind<IPrincipal>().ToConstant(mockPrincipal.Object);

    //Asserts
    var principal = Kernel.Get<IPrincipal>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(principal.Identity.GetUserId());
    Assert.IsTrue(principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
}
```

I've tested using **GenericIdentity** too. Using that i can mock **GetUserId()**, but i can't mock **IsAuthenticated** property.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5):

You get the `NotSupportedException`because `GetUserId` is an extension method  from **[IdentityExtensions.GetUserId Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid(v=vs.108).aspx)**  and does not belong to the mocked object. There is no need to mock `GetUserId`.

If you look at the source code for `GetUserId` you will see what it is not working for you.

```
/// <summary>
///     Extensions making it easier to get the user name/user id claims off of an identity
/// </summary>
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Return the user name using the UserNameClaimType
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetUserName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Return the user id using the UserIdClaimType
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Return the claim value for the first claim with the specified type if it exists, null otherwise
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity"></param>
    /// <param name="claimType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var claim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
        return claim != null ? claim.Value : null;
    }
}
```

It is looking for a `ClaimsIdentity` with a `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, which it why it worked for `GenericIdentity`. So that mean that you would need to create a stub of the Identity. In order to get `IsAuthenticated` to work you just need to provide an authentication Type in the constructor. An empty string will work.

Here is your test method with the changes

```
[Test]
public void Should_GetUserId_From_Identity() {
    //Arrange
    var username = "test@test.com";
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "");
    var nameIdentifierClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username);
    identity.AddClaim(nameIdentifierClaim);

    var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity);
    mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

    Kernel.Rebind<IPrincipal>().ToConstant(mockPrincipal.Object);

    //Act
    var principal = Kernel.Get<IPrincipal>();

    //Asserts        
    Assert.AreEqual(username, principal.Identity.GetUserId());
    Assert.IsTrue(principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
}
```

Comment: It works! I was instantiating GenericIdentity with an empty string as a parameter. 

Really thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. If you found this answer useful, up-vote it. If this answer resolves your issue, mark it as answered. Thanks. Happy coding!!